# Abrir puertos del router para Node.js

Tags: nodejs, router, puertos, ip, tcp

Intento crear un server con la libreria NET de Nodejs dentro de Docker:

```
var HOST = '192.168.1.128';
var PORT = 4757;

net.createServer(function(socket) {
 ...
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Si accedo desde mi movil, conectado al mismo wifi, puedo acceder sin problemas, pero si lo hago conectado a Datos Móviles, no puedo acceder.

Mi router tiene una IP pública (Estoy fuera de CGNAT) y se supone que tengo mi puerto abierto (La misma IP y el mismo puerto que pongo arriba con TCP y UDP). En el apartado DMZ también he puesto: 192.168.1.128

¿Como puedo acceder con datos móviles a este servidor Nodejs?

EDITO 
Ya puedo acceder mediante ip_public:port cuando ejecuto el programa fuera de docker, pero cuando intento acceder mediante un contenedor me da el siguiente fallo:

```
  node_1          | events.js:174
  node_1          |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  node_1          |       ^
  node_1          | 
  node_1          | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED public_ip*:4757
  node_1          |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]     (net.js:1097:14)
  node_1          | Emitted 'error' event at:
  node_1          |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
  node_1          |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
  node_1          |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

public_ip*: IP pública del router

Comment: Estás accediendo con `PublicIP:Port`, ¿verdad? ¿Te aseguraste de comprobar que los puertos estén correctamente abiertos?

Comment: ¿Como lo puedo comprobar exactamente? Con Netstat  me sale la IP y el puerto que asigné como LISTEN. No es la IP pública, si la pongo Nodejs me tira un error.

Comment: con datos publicos te encuentras en otro segmento de red

Comment: Gracias por el comentario JackNavaRow , entonces, ¿Hay alguna manera de crear un servidor Net en Nodejs con una IP pública, dentro de un contenedor de Docker?